# How to make HTML IFrames talk to each other?

Tags: javascript, html, iframe

How to make HTML IFrames talk to each other? So I have 2 Iframes I know and create thare contents. I need to make tham talk one to other - for example one to send XML data to other or just call JS function from it.

Comment: I seriously recommend you abandon using iframes and use AJAX instead. Iframes are practically obsolete now that AJAX has proper support in all major browsers. Picking up a JavaScript library like jQuery or Prototype will also make things a lot easier.

Comment: @Atli - Ditto. <iframe class="obsolete"></iframe>

Comment: Why would you use AJAX if the answer is so simple? Who said iframes are obsolete anyway?

Comment: @ChaosPandion - The W3C, for one. Frames, including iframes, have been deprecated since HTML4 strict. Only the more lenient DTDs allow them. - More to the point, an Iframe is essentially just an AJAX call dumped into a block element, over which you have very little control (relatively). Using AJAX you have complete control over everything, down to where/how it is displayed. It is also far easier to use with CSS than frames are. - Why would you subject yourself to the limitations of a frame when AJAX gives you *so* much more power and control?

Comment: Probably because I am tired and want to go home and work on a real project.

Comment: New kids on the block seem to think that AJAX is the answer to all dynamic loading content questions, much like jQuery evangelists seem to think of their library as the answer to all javascript questions. None of which are right in any given way, shape or form.

Comment: There's at least one common use case that actually requires iFrames, even with Ajax: if you want to make cross-domain requests. For instance, Facebook chat uses this: the browser connects to facebook.com, and an iFrame connects to chat.facebook.com, runs the comet and longpolling, and talks to the parent to update the UI.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This method requires each frame to have these functions.

```
function acceptXml(xml) {
    // Process XML
}

function sendXml(frameName, xml) {
    var frame = window.parent.frames[frameName];
    frame.acceptXml(xml);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It could be just a starting point, but  [**this site**](http://www.ajaxify.com/run/crossframe/) proposes a demo on how to do just that with some ajax.